# Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json occurring while installing RapidsAI on Ubuntu18.04 WSL2

Tags: conda, miniconda, rapids

I try to install RapidsAI in Ubuntu18.04 in WSL2 using conda but the installation always stuck after

> repodata message Solving environment: failed with repodata from
> current_repodata.json

This was unexpected.

```
abhipraja@abhipraja:~$ conda create -n rapids-22.06 -c rapidsai-nightly -c nvidia -c conda-forge  \
>     rapids=22.06 python=3.9 cudatoolkit=11.5 \
>     jupyterlab dash graphistry pycaret tensorflow
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                               /  
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package cudatoolkit conflicts for:
rapids=22.06 -> cudatoolkit=11
tensorflow -> tensorflow-base==2.4.1=gpu_py37h29c2da4_0 -> cudatoolkit[version='8.0.*|9.0.*|9.2.*|>=10.0.130,<10.1.0a0|>=10.1.243,<10.2.0a0|>=10.1.168,<10.2.0a0|>=9.2,<9.3.0a0|>=9.0,<9.1.0a0']
pycaret -> xgboost[version='>=0.90'] -> cudatoolkit[version='11.0|11.0.*|11.4|11.4.*|>=11,<12.0a0|>=11.5,<12|>=11.2,<12']
rapids=22.06 -> cucim=22.06 -> cudatoolkit[version='10.0|10.0.*|10.1|10.1.*|10.2|10.2.*|11.0|11.0.*|11.1|11.1.*|>=11,<12.0a0|>=11.2,<12|9.2|9.2.*|11.4|11.4.*|>=11.2,<12.0a0|>=11.0,<=11.5|>=11.0,<=11.6|>=11.0,<=11.7|11.0.*|11.1.*|10.2.*']
tensorflow -> cudatoolkit[version='10.2|10.2.*|11.0|11.0.*|11.1|11.1.*|>=11.2,<12']
cudatoolkit=11.5

Package pyarrow conflicts for:
graphistry -> pyarrow[version='>=0.15.0']
rapids=22.06 -> cudf=22.06 -> pyarrow[version='>=7.0.0,<7.0.1.0a0',build=*cuda]

Package dataclasses conflicts for:
jupyterlab -> jupyter_server[version='>=1.4,<2'] -> dataclasses
tensorflow -> werkzeug[version='>=0.11.10'] -> dataclasses
pycaret -> gensim -> dataclasses

Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
python=3.9 -> openssl[version='>=3.0.3,<4.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
dash -> python[version='2.7.*|>=3.3'] -> ca-certificates
tensorflow -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
pycaret -> python -> ca-certificates
jupyterlab -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates

Package pandas conflicts for:
pycaret -> pandas
graphistry -> pandas[version='>=0.17.0']
pycaret -> mlxtend[version='>=0.17.0'] -> pandas[version='0.25.3.*|>=0.14.0|>=0.22.0|>=0.23.4|>=0.25.3,!=1.0.1,!=1.0.0,!=1.0.2,!=1.1.0|>=0.25.3,!=1.0.1,!=1.0.0,!=1.0.2|>=0.25|>=0.23|>=0.25.3|>=0.19|>=0.19.1|>=0.17.1|>=0.24.0']
graphistry -> pyarrow[version='>=0.15.0'] -> pandas
rapids=22.06 -> cudf=22.06 -> pandas[version='>=1.0,<1.5.0dev0|>=1.1']

Package python conflicts for:
jupyterlab -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.5|>=3.6|>=3.7|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|3.4.*']
rapids=22.06 -> cuda-python[version='>=11.5,<12'] -> python[version='3.8.*|3.9.*|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.6|>=3.7|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
pycaret -> cufflinks-py[version='>=0.17.0'] -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|3.4.*|>=3.3|>=3.7|>=3.6.0|>=3.5|>=2.7|>=3.7.1,<3.8.0a0|>=3.7.0|>=3.4']
jupyterlab -> ipython -> python[version='>=2.7|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3']
python=3.9
rapids=22.06 -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
dash -> python[version='2.7.*|>=3.3|>=3.6']
tensorflow -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.4.*|3.8.*|3.7.*|3.9.*']
tensorflow -> python_abi=3.10[build=*_cp310] -> python[version='3.10.*|>=3.6|>=3|>=3.4|>=3.5|>=3.7|>=3.2|>=3.2,<3.10']
pycaret -> python[version='>=3.6']
dash -> flask[version='>=1.0.4'] -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=2.7|>=2.7|>=3.6|>=3.7|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.4.*|2.7|>=3.3']

Package werkzeug conflicts for:
dash -> flask[version='>=1.0.4'] -> werkzeug[version='>=0.14|>=0.15|>=0.15,<2.0|>=2.0|>=0.7|>=0.7,<1.0.0']
tensorflow -> tensorboard[version='>=1.13.0,<1.14.0a0'] -> werkzeug[version='>=0.11.15|>=1.0.1|>=0.14|>=0.14.1,<1.0a0']
tensorflow -> werkzeug[version='>=0.11.10']

Package pyyaml conflicts for:
pycaret -> mlflow -> pyyaml[version='>=5.0.0|>=5.1']
dash -> pyyaml[version='>=5.1.1']
pycaret -> pyyaml[version='<6.0.0']

Package click conflicts for:
rapids=22.06 -> cucim=22.06 -> click==8.0.4
pycaret -> mlflow -> click[version='<8.1.0|>=7.0']
dash -> flask[version='>=1.0.4'] -> click[version='>=2.0|>=5.1|>=5.1,<8.0|>=7.1.2|>=8.0']

Package notebook conflicts for:
jupyterlab -> nbclassic[version='>=0.2,<1'] -> notebook[version='<7|>=4.2.0']
jupyterlab -> notebook[version='>=4.2|>=4.3|>=4.3.1']

Package jinja2 conflicts for:
pycaret -> pandas-profiling[version='>=2.8.0'] -> jinja2[version='2.11.1.*|>=2.11.1|>=2.7.2|>=2.8']
dash -> flask[version='>=1.0.4'] -> jinja2[version='>=2.10|>=2.10.1|>=2.10.1,<3.0|>=3.0|>=2.4']
jupyterlab -> jinja2[version='>=2.1|>=2.10']
jupyterlab -> jupyter_server[version='>=1.16,<2'] -> jinja2[version='>2.10*|>=3.0.3']

Package decorator conflicts for:
jupyterlab -> ipython -> decorator
rapids=22.06 -> networkx[version='>=2.5.1,<=2.6.3'] -> decorator[version='>=4.3.0,<5']
dash -> plotly -> decorator[version='>=4.0.6']
pycaret -> ipython -> decorator

Package certifi conflicts for:
jupyterlab -> tornado[version='!=6.0.0,!=6.0.1,!=6.0.2'] -> certifi
dash -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
rapids=22.06 -> setuptools[version='>50'] -> certifi[version='>=2016.9.26']
pycaret -> matplotlib-base -> certifi[version='>=2020.06.20']
graphistry -> requests -> certifi[version='>=2017.4.17']

Package pytz conflicts for:
dash -> plotly -> pytz
pycaret -> matplotlib-base -> pytz[version='>=2017.2|>=2020.1|>=2017.3']
graphistry -> pandas[version='>=0.17.0'] -> pytz[version='>=2017.2|>=2020.1|>=2017.3']

Package packaging conflicts for:
pycaret -> packaging
jupyterlab -> packaging
rapids=22.06 -> cudf=22.06 -> packaging
graphistry -> packaging[version='>=20.1']
pycaret -> matplotlib-base -> packaging[version='>=20.0']

Package nccl conflicts for:
pycaret -> xgboost[version='>=0.90'] -> nccl[version='>=2.10.3.1,<3.0a0|>=2.11.4.1,<3.0a0|>=2.12.12.1,<3.0a0|>=2.12.7.1,<3.0a0|>=2.7.8.1,<3.0a0']
tensorflow -> tensorflow-base==2.8.1=cuda112py310h666ff7d_0 -> nccl[version='>=2.11.4.1,<3.0a0|>=2.12.10.1,<3.0a0|>=2.12.12.1,<3.0a0']
rapids=22.06 -> nccl[version='>=2.9.9,<3.0a0']
rapids=22.06 -> cuml=22.06 -> nccl[version='>=2.9.9']

Package _openmp_mutex conflicts for:
rapids=22.06 -> numba[version='>=0.54'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
cudatoolkit=11.5 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.4.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
pycaret -> lightgbm[version='>=2.3.1'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
tensorflow -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.4.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
python=3.9 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=12'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']

Package enum34 conflicts for:
tensorflow -> absl-py[version='>=0.1.6'] -> enum34[version='>=1.0.4|>=1.1.6,<2.0a0']
tensorflow -> enum34[version='>=1.1.6']
pycaret -> numba[version='<0.55'] -> enum34

Package numpy conflicts for:
pycaret -> numpy[version='1.19.5|>=1.17']
pycaret -> boruta_py -> numpy[version='1.10.*|1.11.*|1.12.*|1.13.*|1.15.*|>=1.10.4|>=1.19.5,<2.0a0|>=1.20.2,<2.0a0|>=1.18.4,<2.0a0|>=1.18.1,<2.0a0|>=1.17.2,<2.0a0|>=1.17.0,<2.0a0|>=1.16.4,<2.0a0|>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.11.3|>=1.19.2,<2.0a0|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0|>=1.11|>=1.21.6,<2.0a0|>=1.21.4,<2.0a0|>=1.18.5,<2.0a0|>=1.17.5,<2.0a0|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0|>=1.19.4,<2.0a0|>=1.15.4,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0|>=1.21.2,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6|>=1.14.6,<1.18.0|>=1.12,<1.13.0a0|>=1.14,<1.15.0a0|>=1.13,<1.14.0a0|>=1.10,<1.11.0a0|>=1.11,<1.12.0a0|>=1.21.5,<2.0a0|>=1.12.1,<2.0a0|>=1.11.*|>=1.9.*|>=1.9|>=1.8|>=1.7|>=1.20.3,<2.0a0|>=1.13.3,<2.0a0|>=1.16.0|>=1.14.0|>=1.19|>=1.13|>=1.15.1,<2.0a0|>=1.15.0,<2.0a0|>=1.14.0,<2.0a0|>=1.6.1|>=1.16.0,<1.20|>=1.13.0|>=1.13.3|>=1.9.3|>=1.15|>=1.22.3,<2.0a0|>=1.17.3|>=1.11.2']

Package libstdcxx-ng conflicts for:
tensorflow -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=5.4.0|>=7.5.0|>=9.4.0']
tensorflow -> tensorflow-base==2.8.1=cuda112py310h666ff7d_0 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=12|>=9.3.0|>=7.3.0|>=4.9|>=7.2.0|>=11.2.0']

Package _libgcc_mutex conflicts for:
python=3.9 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=12'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build='conda_forge|main|main']
cudatoolkit=11.5 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.4.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build='conda_forge|main|main']
tensorflow -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.4.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build='conda_forge|main|main']

Package networkx conflicts for:
rapids=22.06 -> networkx[version='>=2.5.1,<=2.6.3']
pycaret -> pandas-profiling[version='>=2.8.0'] -> networkx

Package libgcc-ng conflicts for:
python=3.9 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=12|>=9.4.0|>=9.3.0|>=7.5.0|>=7.3.0']
graphistry -> numpy -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=12|>=9.4.0|>=9.3.0|>=7.5.0|>=7.3.0|>=4.9|>=11.2.0|>=7.2.0']
jupyterlab -> python[version='>=3.7'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=9.4.0|>=12|>=9.3.0|>=7.5.0|>=7.3.0|>=4.9|>=7.2.0']
tensorflow -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=12|>=9.3.0|>=7.3.0|>=4.9|>=7.2.0|>=11.2.0']
tensorflow -> libgcc-ng[version='>=5.4.0|>=7.5.0|>=9.4.0']
dash -> python[version='>=3.6'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=9.4.0|>=12|>=9.3.0|>=7.5.0|>=7.3.0|>=4.9|>=7.2.0']
rapids=22.06 -> cucim=22.06 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=11.2.0|>=12|>=9.3.0|>=9.4.0|>=7.3.0|>=7.5.0']
cudatoolkit=11.5 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=9.4.0']
pycaret -> gensim[version='<4.0.0'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=4.9|>=7.3.0|>=9.3.0|>=7.2.0|>=9.4.0|>=7.5.0|>=12|>=11.2.0']
python=3.9 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.2.0']

Package wheel conflicts for:
python=3.9 -> pip -> wheel
jupyterlab -> jupyter-packaging[version='>=0.7,<1'] -> wheel
tensorflow -> tensorflow-base==2.6.2=cpu_py39h6349a3b_2 -> wheel[version='<0.36|>=0.26|>=0.35|>=0.35,<1|>=0.35,<0.36']

Package pypy3.7 conflicts for:
pycaret -> ipython -> pypy3.7[version='7.3.3.*|7.3.4.*|7.3.5.*|7.3.7.*|>=7.3.3|>=7.3.4|>=7.3.5|>=7.3.7']
tensorflow -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> pypy3.7[version='7.3.3.*|7.3.4.*|7.3.5.*|7.3.7.*|>=7.3.7|>=7.3.5|>=7.3.4|>=7.3.3']
rapids=22.06 -> cupy[version='>=9.5.0,<11.0.0a0'] -> pypy3.7[version='>=7.3.3|>=7.3.4|>=7.3.5|>=7.3.7']
graphistry -> numpy -> pypy3.7[version='7.3.3.*|7.3.4.*|7.3.5.*|7.3.7.*|>=7.3.3|>=7.3.4|>=7.3.5|>=7.3.7']
jupyterlab -> ipython -> pypy3.7[version='7.3.3.*|7.3.4.*|7.3.5.*|7.3.7.*|>=7.3.3|>=7.3.4|>=7.3.5|>=7.3.7']
dash -> python[version='>=3.6'] -> pypy3.7[version='7.3.3.*|7.3.4.*|7.3.5.*|7.3.7.*|>=7.3.7|>=7.3.5|>=7.3.3']

Package six conflicts for:
tensorflow -> tensorflow-base==2.8.1=cuda112py310h666ff7d_0 -> six[version='1.15.0.*|>=1.12|>=1.15,<1.16|>=1.15.0|>=1.6.0|>=1.5.2|>=1.9.0|>=1.9|>=1.12.0|>=1.12.0,<2.0a0']
tensorflow -> six[version='>=1.10.0']

Package traitlets conflicts for:
jupyterlab -> ipython -> traitlets[version='>=4.2.1|>=4.2|>=5|>=5.1.0|>=5.1|>=4.3']
pycaret -> ipython -> traitlets[version='>=4.2.1|>=4.2|>=5|>=4.3.1,<6.0.0|>=4.3.1,<5.0.0|>=4.3.1']

Package tornado conflicts for:
jupyterlab -> tornado[version='!=6.0.0,!=6.0.1,!=6.0.2|>=6.1|>=6.1.0']
jupyterlab -> notebook[version='>=4.3.1'] -> tornado[version='>=4|>=4,<6|>=4.1,<7|>=5.0|>=5.0,<7']

Package pyparsing conflicts for:
pycaret -> matplotlib-base -> pyparsing[version='<3,>=2.0.2|>=2.0.2,!=3.0.5|>=2.0.3,!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6|>=2.2.1|>=2.0.2,<3|>=2.0.2']
jupyterlab -> packaging -> pyparsing[version='<3,>=2.0.2|>=2.0.2,!=3.0.5|>=2.0.2,<3|>=2.0.2']
graphistry -> packaging[version='>=20.1'] -> pyparsing[version='<3,>=2.0.2|>=2.0.2,!=3.0.5|>=2.0.2,<3|>=2.0.2']

Package scipy conflicts for:
pycaret -> boruta_py -> scipy[version='>=0.13.3|>=0.17.0|>=0.18.1|>=1.1.0|>=1.4.1|>=0.18.0|>=1.5.1|>=0.19.1|>=1.3.1|>=0.18|>=1.0.0|>=1.0.0,<1.6|>=1.0.1|>=0.15.2|>=1.0|>=1.3|>=1.3.2|>=0.17']
pycaret -> scipy[version='<=1.5.4']

Package typing_extensions conflicts for:
rapids=22.06 -> cudf=22.06 -> typing_extensions
graphistry -> typing-extensions -> typing_extensions[version='3.10.0.0|3.10.0.0|3.10.0.1|3.10.0.2|4.0.0|4.0.1|4.1.1|4.2.0|3.7.4.3|3.7.4.2|3.7.4.1|3.7.4.1|3.7.4.1|3.7.4.1|3.7.4|3.7.2|3.6.6|3.6.6|3.6.5|4.1.1|3.10.0.2|3.7.4.3|3.7.4',build='pyh06a4308_0|pyh06a4308_0|pyh06a4308_0|py37_1000|py37_0|py38_0|py37hc8dfbb8_2|py_0|pyha770c72_1|pyha770c72_0|pyha770c72_0|pyha770c72_0|pyha770c72_0|pyha770c72_0|pyha770c72_0|pyha770c72_0|py_0|py36h9f0ad1d_3|py27h8c360ce_1|py37_1000|py36_0|py36_0|pyh06a4308_0|py36_0']
tensorflow -> tensorflow-base==2.8.1=cuda112py310h666ff7d_0 -> typing_extensions[version='3.7.4.*|>=3.6.6|>=3.7.4,<3.8|>=3.7.4']
pycaret -> spacy -> typing_extensions[version='>=3.7.4|>=3.7.4,<4.0.0.0|>=3.7.4.1,<4.0.0.0']

Package importlib-metadata conflicts for:
dash -> flask[version='>=1.0.4'] -> importlib-metadata[version='>=3.6.0']
pycaret -> mlflow -> importlib-metadata[version='>=0.20']
tensorflow -> markdown[version='>=2.6.8'] -> importlib-metadata[version='>=4.4']

Package requests conflicts for:
dash -> plotly -> requests
graphistry -> requests
tensorflow -> tensorboard[version='>=2.6.0'] -> requests[version='>=2.21.0|>=2.21.0,<3']
jupyterlab -> jupyterlab_server[version='>=2.10,<3'] -> requests
pycaret -> mlflow -> requests[version='2.23.0.*|>=2.11.0,<3.0.0|>=2.13.0,<3.0.0|>=2.17.3|>=2.24.0|>=2.23.0|>=2.22']

Package flask conflicts for:
dash -> flask[version='>=0.12|>=1.0.2|>=1.0.4']
dash -> flask-compress -> flask

Package futures conflicts for:
jupyterlab -> futures
graphistry -> pyarrow[version='>=0.15.0'] -> futures
tensorflow -> grpcio[version='>=1.8.6'] -> futures[version='>=2.2.0|>=3.1.1']

Package openblas conflicts for:
graphistry -> numpy -> openblas[version='0.2.18.*|0.2.18|0.2.18.*|0.2.19|0.2.19.*|0.2.20|0.2.20.*|>=0.2.20,<0.2.21.0a0|>=0.3.3,<0.3.4.0a0|>=0.2.15']
tensorflow -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> openblas[version='0.2.18.*|0.2.18|0.2.18.*|0.2.19|0.2.19.*|0.2.20|0.2.20.*|>=0.2.20,<0.2.21.0a0|>=0.3.3,<0.3.4.0a0|>=0.2.15']
pycaret -> numpy -> openblas[version='0.2.18.*|0.2.18|0.2.18.*|0.2.19|0.2.19.*|0.2.20|0.2.20.*|>=0.2.20,<0.2.21.0a0|>=0.3.3,<0.3.4.0a0|>=0.2.15']

Package libprotobuf conflicts for:
graphistry -> protobuf[version='>=2.6.0'] -> libprotobuf[version='3.10.0.*|3.10.1.*|3.11.0.*|3.11.1.*|3.11.2.*|3.11.3.*|3.11.4.*|3.12.1.*|3.12.3.*|3.12.4.*|3.13.0.*|3.13.0.1.*|3.14.0.*|3.15.0.*|3.15.1.*|3.15.2.*|3.15.3.*|3.15.4.*|3.15.5.*|3.15.6.*|3.15.7.*|3.15.8.*|3.16.0.*|3.17.0.*|3.17.1.*|3.17.2.*|3.18.0.*|3.18.1.*|3.19.1.*|3.19.2.*|3.19.3.*|3.19.4.*|3.20.0.*|3.20.1.*|>=3.20.1,<3.21.0a0|>=3.20.0,<3.21.0a0|>=3.19.4,<3.20.0a0|>=3.19.3,<3.20.0a0|>=3.19.2,<3.20.0a0|>=3.19.1,<3.20.0a0|>=3.18.1,<3.19.0a0|>=3.18.0,<3.19.0a0|>=3.17.2,<3.18.0a0|>=3.17.1,<3.18.0a0|>=3.17.0,<3.18.0a0|>=3.16.0,<3.17.0a0|>=3.15.8,<3.16.0a0|>=3.15.7,<3.16.0a0|>=3.15.6,<3.16.0a0|>=3.15.5,<3.16.0a0|>=3.15.4,<3.16.0a0|>=3.15.3,<3.16.0a0|>=3.15.2,<3.16.0a0|>=3.15.1,<3.16.0a0|>=3.15.0,<3.16.0a0|>=3.14.0,<3.15.0a0|>=3.13.0.1,<3.14.0a0|>=3.13.0,<3.14.0a0|>=3.12.4,<3.13.0a0|>=3.12.3,<3.13.0a0|>=3.12.1,<3.13.0a0|>=3.11.4,<3.12.0a0|>=3.11.3,<3.12.0a0|>=3.11.2,<3.12.0a0|>=3.11.1,<3.12.0a0|>=3.11.0,<3.12.0a0|>=3.10.1,<3.11.0a0|>=3.10.0,<3.11.0a0|3.9.2.*|>=3.9.2,<3.10.0a0|3.9.1.*|>=3.9.1,<3.10.0a0|3.9.0.*|>=3.9.0,<3.10.0a0|3.8.0.*|>=3.8.0,<3.9.0a0|3.7.1.*|>=3.7.1,<3.8.0a0|3.7.0.*|>=3.7.0,<3.7.1.0a0|3.6.1.*|>=3.6.1,<3.6.2.0a0|3.6.0.*|>=3.6.0,<3.6.1.0a0|3.5.2.*|3.5.2|3.5.1.1|3.5.1|>=3.5.2,<3.6.0a0|>=3.5.1,<3.6.0a0|>=3.4.1,<3.5.0a0']
tensorflow -> tensorflow-base==2.8.1=cuda112py310h666ff7d_0 -> libprotobuf[version='3.10.0.*|3.10.1.*|3.11.0.*|3.11.1.*|3.11.2.*|3.11.3.*|3.11.4.*|3.12.1.*|3.12.3.*|3.12.4.*|3.13.0.*|3.13.0.1.*|3.14.0.*|3.15.0.*|3.15.1.*|3.15.2.*|3.15.3.*|3.15.4.*|3.15.5.*|3.15.6.*|3.15.7.*|3.15.8.*|3.16.0.*|3.17.0.*|3.17.1.*|3.17.2.*|3.18.0.*|3.18.1.*|3.19.1.*|3.19.2.*|3.19.3.*|3.19.4.*|3.20.0.*|3.20.1.*|>=3.15.7,<3.16.0a0|>=3.15.8,<3.16.0a0|>=3.16.0,<3.17.0a0|>=3.18.1,<3.19.0a0|>=3.19.3,<3.20.0a0|>=3.19.4,<3.20.0a0|>=3.20.1,<3.21.0a0|>=3.20.0,<3.21.0a0|>=3.19.2,<3.20.0a0|>=3.19.1,<3.20.0a0|>=3.18.0,<3.19.0a0|>=3.17.2,<3.18.0a0|>=3.17.1,<3.18.0a0|>=3.17.0,<3.18.0a0|>=3.15.6,<3.16.0a0|>=3.15.5,<3.16.0a0|>=3.15.4,<3.16.0a0|>=3.15.3,<3.16.0a0|>=3.15.2,<3.16.0a0|>=3.15.1,<3.16.0a0|>=3.15.0,<3.16.0a0|>=3.14.0,<3.15.0a0|>=3.13.0.1,<3.14.0a0|>=3.13.0,<3.14.0a0|>=3.12.4,<3.13.0a0|>=3.12.3,<3.13.0a0|>=3.12.1,<3.13.0a0|>=3.11.4,<3.12.0a0|>=3.11.3,<3.12.0a0|>=3.11.2,<3.12.0a0|>=3.11.1,<3.12.0a0|>=3.11.0,<3.12.0a0|>=3.10.1,<3.11.0a0|>=3.10.0,<3.11.0a0|3.9.2.*|>=3.9.2,<3.10.0a0|3.9.1.*|>=3.9.1,<3.10.0a0|3.9.0.*|>=3.9.0,<3.10.0a0|3.8.0.*|3.7.1.*|>=3.7.1,<3.8.0a0|3.7.0.*|>=3.7.0,<3.7.1.0a0|3.6.1.*|>=3.6.1,<3.6.2.0a0|3.6.0.*|>=3.6.0,<3.6.1.0a0|3.5.2.*|3.5.2|3.5.1.1|3.5.1|>=3.5.2,<3.6.0a0|>=3.5.1,<3.6.0a0|>=3.4.1,<3.5.0a0']
tensorflow -> libprotobuf[version='>=3.6.1,<3.7.0a0|>=3.8.0,<3.9.0a0']

Package numexpr conflicts for:
graphistry -> pandas[version='>=0.17.0'] -> numexpr[version='>=2.6.8|>=2.7.0|>=2.7.1']
pycaret -> pandas -> numexpr[version='>=2.6.8|>=2.7.0|>=2.7.1']

Package numba conflicts for:
rapids=22.06 -> numba[version='>=0.54']
rapids=22.06 -> cusignal=22.06 -> numba[version='>=0.49|>=0.49.0']The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.27=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.27=0
  - cudatoolkit=11.5 -> __glibc[version='>=2.17,<3.0.a0']
  - pycaret -> xgboost[version='>=0.90'] -> __cuda
  - pycaret -> xgboost[version='>=0.90'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - python=3.9 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - rapids=22.06 -> cucim=22.06 -> __glibc[version='>=2.17|>=2.17,<3.0.a0']
  - tensorflow -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - tensorflow -> cudatoolkit[version='11.1|11.1.*'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17,<3.0.a0']

Your installed version is: 2.27


abhipraja@abhipraja:~$
```

I was expecting that installation procced normally.

I pasted my software/drivers version details and error below:
Windows 11 Home Single Language: build 22000.708

```
abhipraja@abhipraja:~$ nvidia-smi

Tue Jun  7 19:32:01 2022
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.43.01    Driver Version: 516.01       CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   51C    P8     3W /  N/A |      9MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A        49      G   /Xwayland                       N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
abhipraja@abhipraja:~$ conda --version
conda 4.13.0
```

*I already tried to install RapidsAI on cuda-toolkit previous version(11.5) and conda previous versions and in Ubuntu20.04 and on different python version, but same problem exist. I also try to install from source but same repodata message  stucks the installation*

Comment: @merv using mamba, i gets an error `Encountered problems while solving:
  - package rapids-22.06.00a220517-cuda11_py39_gb6ee04e_57 requires python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed

The environment can't be solved, aborting the operation
error    libmamba Could not solve for environment specs
critical libmamba UnsatisfiableError`